# How to change babel presets for tests

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to run a very simple test with jest and vue-test-utils but I have an error while running my test.
It's a babel preset error :
[image: Error]

And here is my babel.config.json :

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Do someone have any idea what to change in my preset ?

PS : I'm working on a vue-cli project with typescript.